# Not able to zoom on amcharts

Tags: angular, amcharts

i'm trying to make my AMChart zoom correctly, as i'm having data with 2 min. interval and want to be able to look into the data by the minute.

but when i try and 'mark' to zoom or use the buttons to use a defined periode of time. it is just not looking correctly at all. The buttons are giving wrong interval and the zoom will give me vertical lines when zooming into a specific date.

also i have tried to make my Y axis always start from 0, it just do not want to happen.

http://jsfiddle.net/5868z7xw/

anyone who can see what i have done wrong here?

```
this.chart = this.AmCharts.makeChart("m_amcharts_1", {
            "type": "stock",
            "theme": "light",
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN",

            categoryAxis: [{
                gridPosition: "start",
                axisColor: "#DADADA",
                axisAlpha: 0,
                minHorizontalGap: 75,
                startOnAxis: true,
                parseDates: true,
                equalSpacing: true,
                markPeriodChange: false,
                firstDayOfWeek: 0,
                dateFormats: [{
                    period: 'ss',
                    format: 'JJ:NN:SS'
                }, {
                    period: 'mm',
                    format: 'JJ:NN'
                }, {
                    period: 'hh',
                    format: 'JJ:NN'
                }, {
                    period: 'DD',
                    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                }]
            }],
            "guides": [],
            "valueAxes": [{
              "id": "ValueAxis-1",
              "capMaximum": 10,
              "capMinimum": 0,
              "minimum": 0,
              "title": ""
            }],
            "dataSets": [],

            "panels": [ {
              "showCategoryAxis": true,
              "title": "Value",

              "percentHeight": 70,
              "stockGraphs": [ {
                "id": "g1",

                "valueField": "value",
                "comparable": true,
                "compareField": "value",
                "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
                "compareGraphBalloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
              } ],
              "stockLegend": {
                "periodValueTextComparing": "[[percents.value.close]]%",
                "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
              }
            }, 
            {
                "title": "Volume",
                "percentHeight": 30,
                "stockGraphs": [ {
                  "valueField": "volume",
                  "type": "column",
                  "showBalloon": false,
                  "fillAlphas": 1
                } ],

                "stockLegend": {
                  "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
                }
              }
        ],

            "categoryAxesSettings": {
                "maxSeries": 1,
                "groupToPeriods": ["30mm"]
              },

            "chartScrollbarSettings": {
              "graph": "g1"
            },

            "chartCursorSettings": {
              "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
              "fullWidth": true,
              "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
              "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
              "valueLineEnabled": true,
              "valueLineAlpha": 0.5
            },


            "periodSelector": {
                "position": "left",
                "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN",
                "inputFieldWidth": 150,
                "periods": [ {
                  "period": "hh",
                  "count": 1,
                  "label": "1 hour"
                }, {
                  "period": "hh",
                  "count": 2,
                  "label": "2 hours"
                }, {
                  "period": "hh",
                  "count": 5,
                  "selected": true,
                  "label": "5 hour"
                }, {
                  "period": "hh",
                  "count": 12,
                  "label": "12 hours"
                }, {
                  "period": "MAX",
                  "label": "MAX"
                } ]
              },

            "dataSetSelector": {
              "position": "left"
            },
            "panelsSettings": {
                "recalculateToPercents": "never"
              },

            "export": {
              "enabled": true,
              "position": "bottom-right"
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#minPeriod) in your `categoryAxesSettings` to correspond with the smallest interval between the points in your data. By default it is set to days (`"DD"`), so you'll want to change it to minutes (`"mm"`) since that is the smallest interval between your points:

```
categoryAxesSettings: {
  // ...
  minPeriod: "mm",
  // ...
}
```

Also note that your `categoryAxis` setting is incorrect - you can set `categoryAxis` properties inside  `categoryAxesSettings`. Note that [`dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) must contain the complete array for *all* periods, not just the ones you care about. Not including the complete array will cause issues with zooming when you have a lot of data.

As for your valueAxis, you can set it either in the [panel](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#valueAxes) or in [`valueAxesSettings`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ValueAxesSettings) if you want the settings to apply to both panels:

```
valueAxesSettings: {
  // ...
  minimum: 0,
  // ...
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5868z7xw/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to add this proprety to yours:

`"zoomControl": {
        "zoomControlEnabled": true
    }`

[ZoomControl](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/ZoomControl)

Comment: I'm able to zoom, just not able to make it look correctly/decent because the Y axis is changing is bariers and making horizontal lines when zooming in a lot instead of giving me by minute or any smaller amount interval on X

Comment: ahright, did you try to modify the `maxZoomLevel
` property ?

Comment: I'm using stock chart, so don't think maps function will help me with the zooming.